# Linked Lists does not print in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

So basically I'm making a circular linked list and when I try to print out my code nothing gets printed out on the console of Eclipse. What I'm hoping is that all 6 numbers show up on the console. Help me if you can. Thanks so much!

```
public class CircularLinkedList 
{
    public Node head;
    public Node tail;

    public CircularLinkedList()
    {
        head =null;
        tail =null;
    }

    public void insert(int v)
    {   
        if( head == null)
        {
            head = new Node(v, null);
            tail = head;    
        }
        else 
        {   
            Node newNode = new Node(v,head); 
            tail.setNextNode(newNode); 
            tail = newNode;
        }
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        if( head == null)
        {
            System.out.println("The list is empty");
        }
        Node newTemp = head;
        String result = "";
        while(newTemp != head)
        {
            result += newTemp.toString();
            newTemp = newTemp.getNextNode();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CircularLinkedList a = new CircularLinkedList();

        a.insert(1);
        a.insert(2);
        a.insert(3);
        a.insert(4);
        a.insert(5);
        a.insert(6);
        System.out.println(a.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You define `Node newTemp = head;` and then immediately after, have a condition of `while (newTemp != head)` which never executes due to its condition being false.

Comment: @MouseEvent How is it recursive?

Comment: @Siddharth Why do you change the brackets to egyptian style? I guess that's not what OP wants (the original code has normal brackets). You should only correct the formatting, in a way that does not change the original style of the code.

Comment: Can you share the `Node` class also

Comment: Readability is important, SO is the only community where we see a full question without scrolling. I like to keep it clean and remove all of the useless lines of code. There were 15 empty lines, you think we should leave them there too right, so that the style is preserved.

Comment: you should try to add some StringBuilder goodness to your toString implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the `newTemp` is not null in the while loop

```
public String toString() {
    if (head == null) {
        return "";
    }

    String result = "";

    Node temp = head;

    do {
        result += temp.toString();

        temp = temp.getNextNode();

    } while (head != tail && temp != head);
    return result;
}
```

Test

```
CircularLinkedList a = new CircularLinkedList();
System.out.println(a.toString());
a.insert(1);
a.insert(2);
a.insert(3);
System.out.println(a.toString());
a.insert(4);
a.insert(5);
a.insert(6);
System.out.println(a.toString());
```

Result

```
<empty string>
{ "value": 1}{ "value": 2}{ "value": 3}
{ "value": 1}{ "value": 2}{ "value": 3}{ "value": 4}{ "value": 5}{ "value": 6}
```

Comment: The next node of `tail` is `head`, and vice-versa, meaning that `next` is always non-null, so your while loop would execute infinitely.  This is the underlying concept of a circular or doubly-linked list.

Comment: @Vulcan sorry forgot about the circular reference part, corrected

Answer (score 3):

```
Node newTemp = head;
while(newTemp != head)
```

What do you think will happen here? (You forgot to advance newTemp once before starting the loop, OR making it a do... while loop, instead of while)

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate. Sorry I'm such a novice. Another question why doesn't System.out.println(a); work with printing my list?

Comment: There is no error. I'm just curious as to if I didn't use the toString method, why doesn't System.out.println(a) work for printing all my numbers.

Comment: @Amloelxer If there is no error message, then Java auto-magically called `a.toString()` if it expected a string (for example, in printing and in string concatenation Java will auto-magically do this)

Comment: Okay thanks so much. I'm only in first couple months of java so please excuse the novice questions.

Answer (score -1):

You aren't advancing to the next node so your while loop never enters. Also, your `newTemp != head` line might not actually work correctly you might want to store some extra information in your Node class and override the .equals() method to ensure this step works.

```
public String toString()
{
    if( head == null)
    {
        System.out.println("The list is empty");
    }
    Node newTemp = head;
    String result = newTemp.toString(); //Advance to the next node.
    newTemp = newTemp.getNextNode();
    while(newTemp != head) //The root cause of your problem.
    {
        result += newTemp.toString();
        newTemp = newTemp.getNextNode();
    }
    return result;
}
```